# Minimum time required to complete all tasks without altering their order

Tags: c++, hashmap

Minimum time requirement problem:

> Given a string S consisting of N characters (representing the tasks to
> perform) and a positive integer K, the task is to find the minimum
> time required to complete all the given tasks in the given order such
> that each task takes one unit of time and each task of the same type
> must be performed at an interval of K units.

*Link to the question here ->[link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/minimum-time-required-to-complete-all-tasks-without-altering-their-order/)*

I do not understand the following part, specifically what is `curr_time - map` in the following code. In do understand what `curr_time` is but that `curr_time - map` I don't get it.

```
// C++ implementation of
// the above approach
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

// Function to find the minimum
// time required to complete
// tasks without changing their order
void findMinimumTime(string tasks, int K)
{
    // Keeps track of the last
    // time instant of each task
    unordered_map<char, int> map;

    // Stores the required result
    int curr_time = 0;

    // Traverse the given string
    for (char c : tasks) {

        // Check last time instant of
        // task, if it exists before
        if (map.find(c) != map.end()) {

            // Increment the time
            // if task is within
            // the K units of time
            if (curr_time - map <= K) {

                curr_time += K - (curr_time - map) + 1;
            }
        }

        // Update the time of the
        // current task in the map
        map = curr_time;

        // Increment the time by 1
        curr_time++;
    }

    // Print the result
    cout << curr_time;
}

// Driver Code
int main()
{
    string S = "ABACCA";
    int K = 2;
    findMinimumTime(S, K);

    return 0;
}

// This code is contributed by Kingash.
```

Comment: That code doesn't compile. Probably a good reason not to just copy/paste someone else's solution.

Comment: that site is full of poorly written and broken code, this is not an exception unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like they don't check other people's submissions for correctness. In this code, wherever it has `map`, it should have `map[c]`:

```
        if (curr_time - map[c] <= K) {

            curr_time += K - (curr_time - map[c]) + 1;
        }

    ...

    // Update the time of the
    // current task in the map
    map[c] = curr_time;
```

Comment: Oh am just a beginner so i just copy pasted it from there ,but i get it now.